# How to Make 'reactstraps' <Col> accept custom column size and type?

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I am trying to design a dynamic form on ReactJS, to which I can't seem to figure out how to tweak the 'Col' property of 'reactstrap'. Can anyone please suggest me how to do this. I have provided a small codesnippet.

```
let colSize = `${props.colSize}`;
let colType = `${props.colType}`;

<Col colType={colSize}>## Column 1 ##</Col>
```

Comment: you can just use this as written below let classes={props.colTyp :props.colSize} and below you can just write <Col {...classes}>## Column 1 ##</Col>. just  as simple as eating honey..